# How does a Spark task access HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Suppose that

- input to a Spark application is a 1GB text file on HDFS,
- HDFS block size is 16MB,
- Spark cluster has 4 worker nodes.

In the first stage of the application, we read the file from HDFS by `sc.textFile("hdfs://...")`. Since the block size is 16MB, this stage will have 64 tasks (one task per partition/block). These tasks will be dispatched to the cluster nodes. My questions are:

1. Does each individual task fetch its own block from HDFS, or does the driver fetch the data for all tasks before dispatching them, and then sends data to the nodes?
2. If each task fetches its own block from HDFS by itself, does it ask HDFS for a specific block, or does it fetch the whole file and then processes its own block?
3. Suppose that HDFS doesn't have a copy of the text file on one of the nodes, say node one. Does HDFS make a copy of the file on node one first time a task from node one asks for a block of the file? If not, does it mean that each time a task asks for a block of the file from node one, it has to wait for HDFS to fetch data from other nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Spark's access to HDFS is probably as efficient as you think it should be.  Spark uses Hadoop's `FileSystem` object to access data in HDFS.

> Does each individual task fetch its own block from HDFS, or does the driver fetch the data for all tasks before dispatching them, and then sends data to the nodes?

Each task fetches its own block from HDFS.

> If each task fetches its own block from HDFS by itself, does it ask HDFS for a specific block, or does it fetch the whole file and then processes its own block?

It pulls a specific block.  It does not scan the entire file to get to the block.

> Suppose that HDFS doesn't have a copy of the text file on one of the nodes, say node one. Does HDFS make a copy of the file on node one first time a task from node one asks for a block of the file? If not, does it mean that each time a task asks for a block of the file from node one, it has to wait for HDFS to fetch data from other nodes?

Spark will attempt to assign tasks based on the location preferences of the partitions in the RDD.  In the case of a `HadoopRDD` (which you get from `sc.textFile`), the location preference for each partition is the set of datanodes that have the block local.  If a task is not able to be run local to the data, it will run on a separate node and the block will be streamed from a datanode that has the block to the task that is executing on the block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have a follow-up question. Does HDFS or Spark prefetch data for tasks? For example, if node one is going to run 3 tasks on 3 consecutive blocks, would HDFS or Spark prefetch the two consecutive blocks when the first one is fetched?

Comment: Doubtful.  Tasks are pulled from a queue as compute slots become available.  They are not completely predetermined when the job starts.  In this case Spark wouldn't know to prefetch for another task before it has been assigned.

Comment: @smz each block is assigned to corresponding task and that block is read when that task runs. There is no prefetch of data here. Let's take you have 4 blocks and if your worker node has 4 cores then reading these 4 blocks happen parallelly. if your worker node has only 1 core then reading these blocks  happen sequentially where eventually your worker node runs 4 tasks.